# zsh does not find script in PATH while bash does (echo $PATH is the same)

Tags: terminal, bash, path, zsh

I am trying to execute a script using just its name. So naturally I added it to the `PATH` variable. But it seems zsh does not care. If I switch to bash everything works fine. The following terminal snippets happened sequentially without anything in between. I just separated them for readability. I did no funny business in between.

#### The script

```
felix@stochastik3 ~ % cat bin/pluto
#!/usr/bin/env sh
julia --eval "import Pkg; Pkg.add(\"Pluto\"); Pkg.update(\"Pluto\"); import Pluto; Pluto.run()"
```

#### ZSH does not find the script

```
felix@stochastik3 ~ % pluto
zsh: command not found: pluto
```

#### Bash does

```
felix@stochastik3 ~ % bash

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
bash-3.2$ pluto
    Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General.toml`
   Resolving package versions...
  No Changes to `~/.julia/environments/v1.7/Project.toml`
^CERROR: InterruptException:
```

#### Path is the same

```
bash-3.2$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin:~/bin/:
bash-3.2$ exit
exit
felix@stochastik3 ~ % echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin:~/bin/:
felix@stochastik3 ~ % pluto
zsh: command not found: pluto
```

Initially the `PATH` ended with `:~/bin`, I then tried `:~/bin/:`. So that should not be the issue.

Comment: Crossposts should be avoided. Now that you got an answer here, can you delete the other post?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use `~` in your `PATH`. It's a shell shorthand for your home directory, but it won't work in a lot of other cases. The cases where it does work properly are those where the shell expands it into the full path to your home directory before it's actually used. Also, don't put a `/` at the end of a `PATH` entry.

So this is ok, because the shell will expand it before it's added to `PATH`:

```
PATH="$PATH":~/bin
```

The shell will expand the `~` to something like `/Users/stochastik3`, and that'll be added to the `PATH` variable. But if you use this:

```
PATH="$PATH:~/bin"    # Don't do this
```

The `~` is inside double-quotes, so it won't expand properly.

Now, the reason that it works in bash is that bash does its own `PATH` interpretation, and it *does* expand `~` when it finds it in `PATH`. But *nothing else does*. zsh doesn't, ksh doesn't, and probably more importantly the OS doesn't, so a `PATH` entry with `~` won't be recognized in a `find ... -exec`, or `sudo`, or `env`, or... anything other than directly in bash.

Comment: It also worked in `sh` but I assume that is because it happens to be an alias for bash in this case?

Comment: @FelixB. That's correct. On macOS, that is; other OSes may use other shells as `sh`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson : This particular way of bash interpreting `PATH` is creepy. Is this a documented feature? I didn't find it explained in the bash man-page. The closest I found is the explanation of `CDPATH` (not PATH), where the `~` is used in an example.

Comment: @user1934428 I don't know of anyplace it's documented (though that doesn't mean it isn't hidden somewhere). I don't see it in the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Search-and-Execution) either, it just says "... Bash searches each element of $PATH for a directory containing an executable file by that name" without saying anything about how it interprets those elements.